# Use PMD to check someObject.methodCall when someObject exists in base class

Tags: java, spring, sonarqube, findbugs, pmd

We have applications that use the Spring framework's [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) to execute various JDBC statements.  Most of the methods in this class are overloaded.  For example, one version of update() accepts a Map, where the keys are bind variable names, values are variable substitutions.  Another version accepts a SqlParameterSource, which allows column type information to be supplied as well.  I would like to write a rule that flags use of the Map version, because supplying type information [is important for Oracle DBs](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.usn-it.de%2Findex.php%2F2010%2F08%2F04%2Foracle112-mutex-s-too-many-child-cursors%2F&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFkfneo_RL36TokFWhWbmej5GAPUA) if one wants to avoid problems under heavy load.

Some of the code I need to check is written like this:

---- class 1 ----

```
public abstract class BaseDao {
  @Autowired
  NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParamJdbcTemplate;
  ...
}
```

---- class 2 ----

```
public class ThingDao extends BaseDao {
  public int updateTheThing(final Integer thingId, final Integer someVal) {
    final Map<String, Object> sqlParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    sqlParameters.put(":thingIdVar", thingId);
    sqlParameters.put(":otherVar", someVal);

    final String query =
            "UPDATE THINGTABLE SET SOME_FIELD=:otherVar WHERE THING_ID=:thingIdVar";
    return namedParamJdbcTemplate.update(query, sqlParameters);
  }
```

The code in class 2 should cause a violation as it uses a Map, not a SqlParameterSource.

Checking for `update(...)` methods will likely result in false positives as that's a fairly common method name.  I only care about the ones in the specific Spring class.

Note that the `namedParamJdbcTemplate` object is declared in a base class, it is not in the class with the violation.  Also note, it could be called "namedParameterJdbcTemplate" or "template" or anything else the developer wants.

Now, my questions.

1. Is it possible to use PMD to detect violations like this?  Or do I need FindBugs since it analyzes bytecode?
2. If possible with PMD, is it possible using XPath rules or only Java?
3. Can someone please point me at an example of how I would do something like this, preferably with PMD? Findbugs or SonarQube would be okay too?

I have read the [documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.2/howtowritearule.html), particularly the section on rules that analyze more than the class.  I'm not quite sure if the `RuleContext` helps with what I want to do, or how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to write a custom check to raise an issue on a call to a certain method.

As you point it out, you cannot rely on the variable name, so you have to get the types of the object on which you are making the method call which is another level of analysis.
With PMD you would be able to get a call to method named like you want to detect and its number of parameters. But that is not precise enough if you think about method overloading for instance. So you actually have to refer to some type information to be  100% sure.

So:

1. You could but you rule would end up to be very unprecise (but that can be satisfying in some context). Best way would preferably to go with findbugs...
2. I think you can use both.
3. can't really answer for PMD but you can write your own rule using sonarqube rule engine  : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules

This is a feature we actually want to deliver in sonarqube java plugin to be able to access semantic information (types and signification of name) in order to write your own rules using this data.

Comment: A generic FindBugs rule that disallowed any configured list of method signatures would be awesome.

Comment: That is actually an awesome idea for a rule from sonarqube but to reach a generic rule like that there are quite a few challenges to tacle...

Comment: I attempted this with PMD, but eventually abandoned and switched to FindBugs for 2 reasons. One - more precision. I can note where the bug is as well as all parameter set up lines (e.g. Map.put calls) that are missing the type info. Two - FindBugs can be used with plain Maven or wrapped in a Sonar plugin and used there.  [SonarQube is in the process of deprecating PMD rules](http://www.sonarqube.org/tag/pmd/) and having one artifact that can be used in both places is a huge plus for our team.

Comment: @DavidHarkness here you go https://github.com/egnyte/findbugs-3rd-party-deprecating-plugin

Comment: Thanks for pointing this old question back, just for sake of history, there is now a rule template in SonarQube to detect any method  call you specify and raise an issue accordingly.