# Convert FindBugs custom rule to SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

Last year I wrote a custom FindBugs rule with requirements as described in [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25515294/944849).  I would like to write this rule using the new SonarQube Java rules.  I located [general custom rule documentation on SonarQube's site](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Writing+Custom+Rules+using+Java) which links to samples, etc.

Is there documentation describing how to convert a custom FindBugs rule written in Java to SonarQube format?  Given the number of rules the SonarQube team has converted, I was hoping there might be basic guidance to use as a starting point, but I haven't located anything in my Google searching.

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part about rewriting a FindBugs rule in a SonarQube plugin is understanding what the rule does. After that it's just a matter of implementing the proper logic.

Since you wrote the logic of the original rule, you've already won half the battle. The rest is pure implementation & unfortunately there are no shortcuts. If you have specific API questions, though you can get them answered in the [SonarQube Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)